# Unable to retreive unique dates from mysql column having date and time in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, date, distinct

Hi friend am trying to retreive the dates from mysql column named 'date' which has date and time. I want to retreive only dates not times. I want retreive only dates which are not duplicates..

Here is sample data of mysql with column date..

```
   03/07/2017 03:37:12pm
   03/07/2017 10:38:12pm
   04/07/2017 10:38:12pm
   04/07/2017 2:38:12pm
```

wanted out put as

```
     03/07/2017
     04/07/2017
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT  DISTINCT date('d/m/Y,date) FROM video_data";
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
echo $result;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id   = $row['id'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$date</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

?>
```

Am unable to print dates using php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: You miss a single Quote `'d/m/Y',`

Comment: You can use the DATE function to retrieve just the date part, and then use GROUP BY.

Comment: Hint: check for errors after executing SQL Statements `mysqli_error($connection)`

Comment: See [How to get mysqli error in different environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments)

Comment: date column type is ?

Comment: @sravani what is it that u get when you `echo $results`?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Try this SELECT  DISTINCT date_format('d/m/Y',date)  as new_date FROM video_data group by new_date

Comment: @JYoThI Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\video_analysis\pages\videos\summary.php on line 331 is shown

Comment: yes you can't echo the object . so just comment this line // echo $result;  instead of echo you need to use var_dump($result); or print_r($result);

Comment: @JYoThI  its shown like this how can I print date from that mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

Comment: yeah query works . @sravani

Comment: @JYoThI yeah its working am getting only number of rows but unable to print dates

Comment: wait i will update it in answer part

Comment: can you check my below answer @sravani

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id,date FROM video_data";
//echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
//echo $result;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $id   = $row['id'];
 $date = $row['date'];
 $date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: then all dates will come because only time is different

Answer (score 0):

use `Date_format` get the date part from `datetime` column  then apply `distinct` for that column like this

```
SELECT id,DISTINCT date_format(date,'%d/%m/%Y') as new_date FROM video_data group by new_date
```

PHP :

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id,DISTINCT date_format(date,'%d/%m/%Y') as new_date FROM video_data group by new_date";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id   = $row['id'];
    $date = $row['new_date'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$date</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

?>
```

Comment: its printing date as 1970-01-01 if I remove  $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); its printing nothing

Comment: arning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\video_analysis\pages\videos\summary.php on line 331 is shown

Comment: when i give var_dump($result) its showing as bool(false)

Comment: @sravani meaning your query fails... can u paste your query and run it on phpmyadmin

Comment: unable to run the query its showing complete errors0 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "DISTINCT" at position 10)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "DISTINCT" at position 10)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "date_format" at position 19)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 30)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "date" at position 31)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 35)
Unexpected token. (near "'%d/%m/%Y'" at position 36)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 46)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 48)
Unexpected token.

Comment: date column type is ?  @sravani  datetime or varchar  ?

Answer (score 0):

select distinct value from db and convert them according to your need.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM  video_data;"
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $id   = $row['id'];
 $date = $row['date'];
 $date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: its showing only 01/01/1970 this date but its not there in my database  and  Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\video_analysis\pages\videos\summary.php on line 332

Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\xampp\htdocs\video_analysis\pages\videos\summary.php on line 333

Comment: can you please share your **db** or partial data from 'video_data'

Comment: i think your date is stored as '03-07-2017 03:37:12pm' format, is it ?

Comment: id  date video_id  are column names 1 2 3 are ids  04/07/2017 03:37:12pm   04/07/2017 03:37:12pm     04/07/2017 03:37:12pm    are dates with time  JK8CzkQh1FY JK8CzkQh1FY JK8CzkQh1FY are videoids i  need to get the date without duplicates

Comment: date is stored as 04/07/2017 03:37:12pm

Comment: can you please give me the output of -

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM  video_data;"
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     var_dump($row);
}